# Listening comprehension of a short TV commercial

Tags: listening, conversation

I've been struggling with the listening comprehension of a very short TV commercial. Could you please listen to the approximately ten-second conversation from the link indicated below and tell me what **MAN 2** is saying in the statement **in bold font**? I've written down what I think I heard.

> MAN 1: If you had only one choice, what would it be?
>   MAN 2: **Will you actually get it?**
>   MAN 1: Only one.
>   MAN 2: That's a difficult question.
>
> *(Man2 pondering)*
>
> Man 2: Dokodemo door (a Japanese word).
>
> *(Then follows an announcement in Japanese.)*

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QRNugIpIxKk

Comment: That's what I thought Man2 said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got it spot on.  That's exactly what he's saying.

The man's accent is from the North of England (toned down somewhat) - at a push I'd go with Liverpool or the Wirral.

Comment: Gee, thank you very much for your kind comment, Easy Tiger. Your confirmation has really relieved me.